# How to convert a color integer to a hex String in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, colors, hex

I have an integer that was generated from an `android.graphics.Color`.
It has a value of `-16776961`. How do I convert it into a hex string with the format `#RRGGBB`?

Simply put: I would like to output `#0000FF` from `-16776961`.

**Note:** I don't want the output to contain alpha and I have also tried [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506708/android-convert-color-int-to-hexa-string) with no success.

Comment: What are you trying to set the hex color on? I think there's a different answer here

Comment: @Blundell Am exporting the color to an external application. The colour needs to be in this format #RRGGBB

Comment: So what's wrong with  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor(int) ? You'll have to paste the url or scroll to getColor(int)

Comment: Am getting the raw integers. The values are not from a resource ow widget

Answer (score 567, accepted):

The mask makes sure you only get RRGGBB, and the %06X gives you zero-padded hex (always 6 chars long):

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & intColor));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Easier and more accurate than trying to use substring on Integer.toHexString().

Comment: How would it be if I wanted it the other way round, please?

Comment: I've just realized there is Color.parseColor(String hex) method which does exactly what I'm asking for.

Comment: @anoniim you're awesome :) was having trouble with ColorDrawable in Android.

Comment: If RED=0 and GREEN=131 and BLUE=146 the result I get is 02004 instead of 008392. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: SiKini8, this piece of code doesn't take individual r, g, and b parameters, but a single int.  What are you passing for `intColor`?

Comment: int intColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.yourColor);

Comment: How to do reverse of that? For example How to convert hex colour to integer?

Comment: int colorInt = 0xff000000 | Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16);

Comment: Don't use this answer if your color uses alpha. You'll lose it.

Comment: @Simon, to make this alpha-ready just remove the mask and change 6 to 8. Note that OP asked for dismissing alpha.

Comment: This code does not work in Kotlin. Could you post a working Kotlin version pls? :-)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @voghDev, for Kotlin change the `&` to `and`. For example, `val hex = String.format("#%08X", (0xFFFFFF and color))`

Answer (score 61):

Try Integer.toHexString()

Source:
[In Java, how do I convert a byte array to a string of hex digits while keeping leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332079/in-java-how-do-i-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-string-of-hex-digits-while-keeping-le)

Comment: This answer retains the alpha of the color

Comment: Well, if you want to get rid of the alpha, just create a bit mask for it: Integer.toHexString(value & 0x00FFFFFF)

Comment: Java int type is 4 bytes long. According to android.graphics.Color's documentation, the leftest byte is the alpha channel. By using a bit wise AND operation with the value 0x00FFFFFF, you essentially clears the leftest byte (alpha channel) to 0.

When used with Integer.toHexString, it'll just leave the rest of the 3 bytes in String.  All non-significant digits will be dropped from the call, so if you want the leading zeroes, you may have to prepend that in yourself.

Comment: Doesn't work for `0x000000FF`, or `0xFF0000FF` if you remove the alpha.

Answer (score 30):

I believe i have found the answer, This code converts the integer to a hex string an removes the alpha.

```
Integer intColor = -16895234;
String hexColor = "#" + Integer.toHexString(intColor).substring(2);
```

**Note** only use this code if you are sure that removing the alpha would not affect anything.

Comment: If you send `0x00FFFFFF` through this it'll crash `Color.parseColor`.

Comment: @TWiStErRob use `Color.TRANSPARENT` for such case

Answer (score 18):

You can use this for color without alpha:

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & intColor));
```

or this with alpha:

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%08X", (0xFFFFFFFF & intColor));
```

Answer (score 14):

Integer value of ARGB color to hexadecimal string:

```
String hex = Integer.toHexString(color); // example for green color FF00FF00
```

Hexadecimal string to integer value of ARGB color:

```
int color = (Integer.parseInt( hex.substring( 0,2 ), 16) << 24) + Integer.parseInt( hex.substring( 2 ), 16);
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is what i did

```
 int color=//your color
 Integer.toHexString(color).toUpperCase();//upercase with alpha
 Integer.toHexString(color).toUpperCase().substring(2);// uppercase without alpha
```

Thanks guys you answers did the thing

Comment: The first variant doesn't work for `0x00FFFFFF` ->  "FFFFFF" (no alpha). The second variant doesn't work for `0x00000FFF` -> "F" (missing bits).

Comment: @TWiStErRob did you a solution that reliably works for colors with alpha channel?

Comment: @Saket The top answer's variant should: `String.format("#%08X", intColor)`

Comment: @TWiStErRob Ah, just saw your comment under the top answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

With this method *Integer.toHexString*, you can have an Unknown color exception for some colors when using Color.parseColor.

And with this method *String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & intColor))*, you'll lose alpha value.

So I recommend this method:

```
public static String ColorToHex(int color) {
        int alpha = android.graphics.Color.alpha(color);
        int blue = android.graphics.Color.blue(color);
        int green = android.graphics.Color.green(color);
        int red = android.graphics.Color.red(color);

        String alphaHex = To00Hex(alpha);
        String blueHex = To00Hex(blue);
        String greenHex = To00Hex(green);
        String redHex = To00Hex(red);

        // hexBinary value: aabbggrr
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("#");
        str.append(alphaHex);
        str.append(blueHex);
        str.append(greenHex);
        str.append(redHex );

        return str.toString();
    }

    private static String To00Hex(int value) {
        String hex = "00".concat(Integer.toHexString(value));
        return hex.substring(hex.length()-2, hex.length());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use `Integer.toHexString` you will end-up with missed zeros when you convert colors like `0xFF000123`.
Here is my kotlin based solution which doesn't require neither android specific classes nor java. So you could use it in multiplatform project as well:

```
    fun Int.toRgbString(): String =
        "#${red.toStringComponent()}${green.toStringComponent()}${blue.toStringComponent()}".toUpperCase()

    fun Int.toArgbString(): String =
        "#${alpha.toStringComponent()}${red.toStringComponent()}${green.toStringComponent()}${blue.toStringComponent()}".toUpperCase()

    private fun Int.toStringComponent(): String =
        this.toString(16).let { if (it.length == 1) "0${it}" else it }

    inline val Int.alpha: Int
        get() = (this shr 24) and 0xFF

    inline val Int.red: Int
        get() = (this shr 16) and 0xFF

    inline val Int.green: Int
        get() = (this shr 8) and 0xFF

    inline val Int.blue: Int
        get() = this and 0xFF
```

Answer (score 1):

Simon's solution works well, alpha supported and color cases with a leading "zero" values in R, G, B, A, hex are not being ignored. A slightly modified version for java Color to hex String conversion is:

```
    public static String ColorToHex (Color color) {
    int red = color.getRed();
    int green = color.getGreen();
    int blue = color.getBlue();
    int alpha = color.getAlpha(); 

    String redHex = To00Hex(red);
    String greenHex = To00Hex(green);
    String blueHex = To00Hex(blue);
    String alphaHex = To00Hex(alpha);

    // hexBinary value: RRGGBBAA
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("#");
    str.append(redHex);
    str.append(greenHex);
    str.append(blueHex);
    str.append(alphaHex);

    return str.toString();
}

private static String To00Hex(int value) {
    String hex = "00".concat(Integer.toHexString(value));
    hex=hex.toUpperCase();
    return hex.substring(hex.length()-2, hex.length());
}
```

another solution could be:

```
public static String rgbToHex (Color color) {

   String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x%02x", color.getRed(), color.getGreen(), color.getBlue(), color.getAlpha() );
   hex=hex.toUpperCase();
       return hex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String int2string = Integer.toHexString(INTEGERColor); //to ARGB
String HtmlColor = "#"+ int2string.substring(int2string.length() - 6, int2string.length()); // a stupid way to append your color
```

Answer (score 0):

use this way in Koltin

```
var hexColor = "#${Integer.toHexString(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorTest))}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixing alpha issue in Color picker libraries.

if you get an integer value in return when you pick color first convert it into the hex color.

```
    String hexVal = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFFFF & 
    color)).toUpperCase();

    int length=hexVal.length();
    String withoutHash=hexVal.substring(1,length);


    while (withoutHash.length()<=7)
    {

        withoutHash="0"+withoutHash;

    }
    hexVal ="#"+withoutHash;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new Kotlin 1.9.0 standard library [`HexFormat`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-hex-format.html):
(don't forget to add `@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)` where needed)

```kotlin
val myHexFormat = HexFormat {
    upperCase = false
    number.prefix = "#"
    number.removeLeadingZeros = true
}
val myInt = 0xb40e89
myInt.toHexString(myHexFormat)         // #b40e89
```

You could also use the Kotlin predefined `HexFormat`s:

```kotlin
val myInt = 0xb40e89
myInt.toHexString(HexFormat.Default)   // 00b40e89
myInt.toHexString(HexFormat.UpperCase) // 00B40E89
```

---

To exclude the alpha from an ARGB integer, do this workaround:

```kotlin
(myInt and 0xFFFFFF).toHexString(myHexFormat)
```

And vote for this issue: [Cannot ignore alpha when formatting with HexFormat](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-60787)