# How to Convert #RGBto #RRGGBB

Tags: android, colors, hex, rbga

I have to convert a color string in the format #RGB to #RRGGBB  like #0af To #RRGGBB now can any one help out here using android

Comment: `#0AF` == `#00AAFF` . what else do you want ?

Comment: i want it using coding of android

Comment: and what have you tried ?

Comment: i doesnt find any clue how to do it

Comment: This requires basic programming skills in Java, nothing else. If you don't have them, think twice about whether or not to proceed from here.

Comment: @ClassStacker I know i can do it using java code ,but i just want to find any predefined method which can give me my required result ....here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539879/how-to-convert-a-color-integer-to-a-hex-string-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & intColor));
```

thats what i was searching. It will ensure that color string always will be #RRGGBB.

Comment: Oh really? I think it's obvious that this doesn't do what you asked for.

Comment: @ClassStacker thanks for ur suggestions but i dont think u r a right person to tell me what i asked is wrong or right ...ok ...enjoy . \m/

Comment: Oh, am I not? That surprises me. Because Daryn and @Dmitry Bychenko spent their time on answers which are based on an interpretation of your question which matches mine. I'd call that a majority. But I presume you're just after as much free code as possible. And you're very young, that explains a lot. Farewell, my friend!

Answer (score 3):

One way is:

```
String rgb = "#0AF";
String rrggbb = "#";
for (int i = 1; i < rgb.length(); i++) {
    rrggbb += (rgb.charAt(i) + "" + rgb.charAt(i));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int newRgb = 17 * (((oldRgb & 0xF00) << 8) | ((oldRgb & 0xF0) << 4) | (oldRgb & 0xF));
```

Comment: oldRgb is supposed to be int as well as newRgb