# Set transparency of listview item in code

Tags: android, listview

I am setting the background of listview items in code like this:

```
RelativeLayout root;
root = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.root);
root.setBackgroundColor(-14774017);
```

This sets the background colour correctly, but at 100% opacity. I would like to set the transparency of the relativelayout background. I understand that hex-codes can have alpha values at the start in android - eg `#AARRGGBB`, but how would I add transparency to the background when I am using an integer colour value (for example `-14774017`)?

Comment: Why do you have to use an integer? Check this if you have no choice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539879/how-to-convert-a-color-integer-to-a-hex-string-in-android

Comment: @YoannHercouet I have no choice in the matter. Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color int value contains all the alpha, red, green and blue components.

> The components are stored as follows (alpha << 24) | (red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue. Each component ranges between 0..255 with 0 meaning no contribution for that component, and 255 meaning 100% contribution.

The [`Color`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class provides utility methods to extract or combine these components. The following snippet will create a color `int` from the user-specified color and alpha values:

```
int alpha = 128; //50% transparency
int color = -14774017; //Your color value
int bgColor = Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));

root.setBackgroundColor(bgColor);
```

Comment: You read my question correctly and gave a perfect solution. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Create a XML color resource file:

ex: `/res/values/colors.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <color name="list_background">#66A4C739</color>
</resources>
```

Then in your `Fragment` or `Activity`,

```
RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.root);
root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(yourpackage.R.color.list_background));
```

If you're not doing this in a `Fragment` or an `Activity`, you need a `Context`:

```
context.getResources().getColor(yourpackage.R.color.list_background));
```

Comment: I cannot hardcode the colour value. It is passed to the activity at run-time as an integer value (not as a hex code).

Comment: Fair enough. Next time, try to add more context to your question. :)