# HTML Color text to HEX values

Tags: java, android, html, colors

I am working on an Android app, which uses some html data from a website. I have a few pieces of text that are using html colors. Like 'red' or 'green'. Is there any way to convert those strings to HEX values in Java?

Comment: There is a table: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors (I'm not aware of a method that converts for you though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return a color `int`

```
int intColor = android.graphics.Color.parseColor("red") //  -65536
```

Then you can convert to HEX like so:

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & intColor));
```

- int to HEX conversion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6540378/363701
- [android.graphics.Color documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#RED)

Answer (score 3):

String hexvalue = Integer.toHexString(Color.parseColor("red"));

//hexvalue is now "ffffff00"

Comment: [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) Also, this doesn't seem to go to HEX, unless I'm confused.

Comment: [Instructions on doing the int -> hex` conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539879/how-to-convert-a-color-integer-to-a-hex-string-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You could easily add the list of HTML colors within your app and translate them.  140 color names are defined in the HTML and CSS color specification.  The [list is here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp).

Given that, it would be trivial to have a HashMap that translates the color names into the appropriate Hex code.

You could also use `Color.parseColor` [as defined here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor%28java.lang.String%29).  That would yield an android color-int, which can be converted to hex like this:

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & intColor));
```

Answer (score 0):

If they're using standard CSS 'red' and 'green' then it's equivilent to #FF0000 (rgb(255,0,0)) and #00FF00 (rgb(0,255,0)) respectively.

You can also look-up any hex value for a named color in the CSS standard easily at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colornames.asp