# getCurrentTextColor returns int, I want hex color value

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to compare the hex color value string to the color of textview which changes color every few seconds.

At the moment getCurrentTextColor for the textview returns a large minus number, rather than the hex value of the color.

How would I turn this number into it's hex value? is this possible?

thanks

Comment: yes, I need to extract the hex color of a textview :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a color integer to a hex String in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539879/how-to-convert-a-color-integer-to-a-hex-string-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont turn them to hex value. Just compare the `getCurrentTextColor` with the curresponding hex value

sample:

```
if (textView.getCurrentTextColor() == 0xff4444)
```

Comment: the hex value is set in a tag of a button, what should I cast this to? Casting to integer does not seem to give me the same value as getCurrentTextColor.

Comment: @user1795294 use this Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(String));

Comment: @user1795294 make sure that you cast it to string

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6540378/1313268).

`String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & intColor));`