# How to get accent color programmatically?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-styles

How would one fetch the accent color set in styles, like below, programmatically?

```
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/material_green_500</item>
```

Comment: Anyone down-voting should feel very free indeed to post their thoughts in comment...

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You can fetch it from the current theme in this way:

```
private int fetchAccentColor() {
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();

    TypedArray a = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, new int[] { R.attr.colorAccent });
    int color = a.getColor(0, 0);

    a.recycle();

    return color;
}
```

Comment: What about the support version?

Comment: This is the support version.

Comment: can we set RGB  string in colorPrimary in styles.xml or colors.xml??

Comment: This is returning a negative number for me.  Is this still the valid way to get the accent color?

Comment: What typedValue.data does reference to?

Comment: I am too getting a negative value. IS there any solution for this.

Comment: @Naveed Re: negative numbers: color ints can be negative, that's fine.

Comment: I get same problem negetive value, and it falls :(

Comment: For the people asking why is the method returning a negative number, is it because you expect a hex? If so, check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49896254/6138589

Comment: This returns for me the color for my app's theme rather than the custom button theme I want to call it for. How do I call for subthemes?

Comment: @rciovati is it possible we can set accent color programmatically?

Answer (score 53):

This also worked for me:

```
public static int getThemeAccentColor (final Context context) {
    final TypedValue value = new TypedValue ();
    context.getTheme ().resolveAttribute (R.attr.colorAccent, value, true);
    return value.data;
}
```

Comment: I get same problem also in this solution, negetive value, and it falls :(

Comment: Negative value is fine. It's a color!

Comment: but my aplication craches down with eroor no resource found ... this is not happenning when i put a regular color! so the value is not fine

Comment: Then where is the negative value coming from if the resource is not found? All I'm saying is that 0xff2506ac (for example) is negative number and a valid color value.

Comment: I also find negative value and facing exception. a large negative integer

Comment: The negative value that you get is _the actual color_ **not** the resource id. Don't use it as a resource id.

Answer (score 32):

```
private static int getThemeAccentColor(Context context) {
    int colorAttr;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        colorAttr = android.R.attr.colorAccent;
    } else {
        //Get colorAccent defined for AppCompat
        colorAttr = context.getResources().getIdentifier("colorAccent", "attr", context.getPackageName());
    }
    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(colorAttr, outValue, true);
    return outValue.data;
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that do not rely on importing the app R class, which is ideal for building custom views.

Answer (score 24):

For those of you using Kotlin

```
@ColorInt
fun Context.themeColor(@AttrRes attrRes: Int): Int = TypedValue()
    .apply { theme.resolveAttribute (attrRes, this, true) }
    .data
```

Answer (score 12):

I have an static method on a utils class to get the colors from the current theme. Most of times is colorPrimary, colorPrimaryDark and accentColor, but you can get a lot more.

```
@ColorInt
public static int getThemeColor
(
        @NonNull final Context context,
        @AttrRes final int attributeColor
)
{
    final TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme ().resolveAttribute (attributeColor, value, true);
    return value.data;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Here's my take on this:

```
public static String getThemeColorInHex(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String colorName, @AttrRes int attribute) {
    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(attribute, outValue, true);
    } else {
        // get color defined for AppCompat
        int appCompatAttribute = context.getResources().getIdentifier(colorName, "attr", context.getPackageName());
        context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(appCompatAttribute, outValue, true);
    }
    return String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & outValue.data));
}
```

Usage:

```
    String windowBackgroundHex = getThemeColorInHex(this, "windowBackground", android.R.attr.windowBackground);
    String primaryColorHex = getThemeColorInHex(this, "colorPrimary", R.attr.colorPrimary);
```

Comment: The `String.format()` helps to explain how to convert the negative integer value to a hex color string.

Comment: This is a much better / generic solution than the accepted answer for this question!

Comment: Also useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539879/how-to-convert-a-color-integer-to-a-hex-string-in-android

Comment: Thank you for this! +1

Answer (score 5):

The MaterialColors could be used in this case if you want it to be single line

```
            MaterialColors.getColor(context, R.attr.colorAccent,context.getResources().getColor(R.color.fall_back_color));
```

The first argument is the context the second argument is the attribute you need to get and the third argument is the fallback color incase the attribute is missing or something goes wrong while getting the attribute color

Comment: One note. This will not work from service or application context until you set manually in App: applicationContext.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme).

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin solution:

```
    context.obtainStyledAttributes(TypedValue().data, intArrayOf(R.attr.colorAccent)).let {
        Log.d("AppLog", "color:${it.getColor(0, 0).toHexString()}")
        it.recycle()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use **Theme.Material3** you have to combine both solutions mentioned here because one works for **R.attr** and another one for **android.R.attr**.

```
@ColorInt
fun Context.getThemeColor(@AttrRes attrRes: Int): Int {
    val materialColor = MaterialColors.getColor(this, attrRes, Color.BLUE)
    if (materialColor< 0) return materialColor

    val resolvedAttr = TypedValue()
    theme.resolveAttribute(attrRes, resolvedAttr, true)
    val colorRes = resolvedAttr.run { if (resourceId != 0) resourceId else data }
    return ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorRes)
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `defaultValue` be something like `-1` instead of `Color.BLUE`? Also, the if condition should check if returned value is not `defaultValue`. e.g. `if (materialColor != defaultValue)`