# How to retrieve the value of an attribute's theme, in my case R.attr.colorPrimaryDark, programmatically?

Tags: android-theme

I want to retrieve the value of `R.attr.colorPrimaryDark`.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611173/how-to-get-accent-color-programmatically) answer but it doesn't work for me, maybe is too old. Also the Android documentation doesn't help me too.

Comment: Could you add some code. Is an exception get thrown or you get the wrong value ?

Comment: Sorry man, but I solved the problem. I think the problem was that I can't get the ``Theme`` from the ``Application``'s ``Context``. So, using the ``Context`` from an ``Activity`` solved the problem.