# Change toolbar color from transparent to primary programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

[From these answers, I suppose I know how to grab the primary color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27611173/how-to-get-accent-color-programmatically). However, when I try to set the background color of the toolbar, I keep getting exception that the resourceId for the color I am specifying is not found

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID ...
```

I have tried

```
toolbar.setBackgroundResource(primaryColor);
```

and I have tried

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(primaryColor);
```

Comment: toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primaryColor));

Answer (score 0):

I think that in your case, you are passing the resource id of the color as the argument to the `setBackgroundColor` method. You want to pass the integer that the color actually evaluates to instead. There are a number of ways to do this depending on what information you have (hex string, rgb integer values, etc. Check out the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) for more info on defining a color value.

Assuming that your color is defined in `colors.xml` in your `res/values` folder, you should be able to simply use this:

```
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primaryColor);
```

Otherwise, you'll have to define your color programmatically first as I mentioned.