# How to programmatically change the colour of a textView, to a colour saved in an attributes file?

Tags: android

Apologies if this is a duplicate question but I'm struggling to find the syntax needed to do what I want.

I have an attributes file in my resources where i store a bunch of different colours, and have been settings them in xml like so:

```
android:textColor="?attr/textcolor"
```

Say I have a TextView called textView in my Java. How can I do the same task programmatically? I'm thinking it must be something similar to:

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(...))
```

But I can't figure out exactly what I need to write.

Cheers

Comment: Have you checked with `R.color.textcolor`?

Comment: @JeelVankhede, yes, it says it can not resolve symbol textcolor. I think it's looking for it in my colors.xml file, but I need it to look in my attr.xml file, hence I am wondering what the syntax is.

Comment: It would be `R.attr` but you won't be able to set color from it *(because it wouldn't find in it)*, i would suggest you put color into `colors.xml`

Comment: @JeelVankhede I'm using R.attr because I have a day and night mode, and the attr file sets the names of the different styles in my styles file, where the colours are stored.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611244/7319704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First define Color you want to set on Textview via color.xml file, for example ->

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
```

Then inside your java file, This single line will set color on textview, note that the color will be fetched from defined colors inside color.xml file. ->

```
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Comment: @Roonil, Don't forget to add Appropriate color in color.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
int[] attrs = {R.attr.textcolor};
TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
int color = typedArray.getResourceId(0, android.R.color.black);
typedArray.recycle();

textView.setTextColor(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the view that has been cast from the `TextView` class not the `TextView` class itself. 
use

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(...);
textView.setTextColor(getResource().getColor(R.color.black
```

));

then store your colors in `color.xml` file not attributes, unless you want to use something more than only color

example

```
<color name="black">#000000</color>
```