# Android color code WHITE conversion to hexadecimal

Tags: android-canvas, paint, android-custom-view, android

I am working with hybrid android application where i need to pass color code from java class to html. My HTML code is expecting "#RGB", where as in my android code declared some color as `Color.WHITE and Color.TRANSPARENT whose equivalent int values are -1 and 0`

How can i convert `Color.WHITE i.e (-1)` to some `#FFFFFF`?

I know `Color.parseColor(#FFFFFF)` but i need reverse one.

Comment: Already asked before more than once. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539879/how-to-convert-a-color-integer-to-a-hex-string-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since color is actually an integer, you can easily convert it to hexadecimal with `String.format`. It seems you want to ignore the alpha channel so you can filter it out:

```
String.format("#%06X", color & 0xffffff);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this out

```
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & intColor));
```

[Reference here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539879/how-to-convert-a-color-integer-to-a-hex-string-in-android)