# "0xF4000000" String conversion to int in java

Tags: java, caching, tlb

I have a file which consists data shown in the image. I need to read this data and pass it to a method which accepts integer values only. So I have to convert this string data into Int. But is shows NumberFormatException.java:65. Please Help.
[error I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aAQk.png)

[Data I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8y5o.png)

Comment: Please check [ask]. In particular, post the code (and error) here, with the proper format, so it's easier to view your question.

Comment: And [don't just post image without code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Answer (score 0):

0xF4000000 is a hex string that equals to 4093640704 and it's too large for int. Use Long for converting hex string to number:

```
Long number = Long.parseLong("F4000000", 16);
```

Long.parseLong doesn't accept prefix `0x` so you can exclude it:

```
Long number = Long.parseLong("0xF4000000".replace("0x", ""), 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one to convert hexstring int color code to get a int value from hextstring
int color = (Integer.parseInt( hex.substring( 0,2 ), 16) << 24) + Integer.parseInt( hex.substring( 2 ), 16);
reference 
[How to convert a color integer to a hex String in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539879/how-to-convert-a-color-integer-to-a-hex-string-in-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)