# Convert from Android color to HTML color

Tags: java, android, html, colors

I want to know how this conversion could be done:

I've checked  that the following instruction:

```
 int color= ((ColorDrawable)  dialog1.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).getBackground()).getColor();
```

Gives in some devices the result color=-12434878, it's checked that the color is equivalent to the HTML color #424242.

But point is I see no way for transforming from one to the other and neither I find any reference for this.

How could this be done?

Comment: Can you check which colors correspond to the colors `#000000` and `#ffffff`? It seems, that you can just add 16⁶ to that value and convert it to a base-16 string. You need that in Java, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly in Java, I've checked that #FFFFFF is -1 and #000000 is -16777216, now I can see the pattern, problem was that negative sign was confusing me. Thanks a lot for your tip.

Comment: I think you are looking for this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6540378/614807

Answer (score 2):

Convert integer to hex String

```
Integer intColor = -12434878;
String hexColor = "#" + Integer.toHexString(intColor).substring(2);
```

Comment: Have you got the solution? @user2638180

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I made an error when posting, the color is retrieved only if it set before, so on last term this doesn't help me.